# jquery Dialog - Focus on next textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a dialog with a large form (each form element is wrapped in a DIV, and there are also labels/tooltips/etc). Whenever a user hits 'tab', I want it to focus on the next div (.fm-req) input (.defaultTextBox2). Here's an example of the HTML:

```
<div class="fm-req">
    <label for="">Answer <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="<?php echo $p;?>" title="Coming Soon..." class="tooltip_popup"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a></label>
    <input name="answer" class="validate[required] defaultTextBox2" maxlength="200" type="text" />
    <input type="button" name="default" value="Default">
</div>
<div class="fm-req">
    <label for="">Answer2 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="<?php echo $p;?>" title="Coming Soon..." class="tooltip_popup"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a></label>
    <input name="answer2" class="defaultTextBox2 percent" type="text" />
</div>
```

There could be many of these with a few different variations. However, I just want to focus on the next .fm-req.defaultTextBox2. I've started with something like:

```
$(".defaultTextBox2").keydown(function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 9) { // 9 is tab key
         $(this).find('.fm-req').next('.defaultTextBox2').focus();
    }
});
```

But I can't seem to get it working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for javascript, just use the HTML `tabindex` attribute:

```
<div class="fm-req">
    <label for="">Answer <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="<?php echo $p;?>" title="Coming Soon..." class="tooltip_popup"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a></label>
    <input tabindex="1" name="answer" class="validate[required] defaultTextBox2" maxlength="200" type="text" />
    <input type="button" name="default" value="Default">
</div>
<div class="fm-req">
    <label for="">Answer2 <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="<?php echo $p;?>" title="Coming Soon..." class="tooltip_popup"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a></label>
    <input tabindex="2" name="answer2" class="defaultTextBox2 percent" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".defaultTextBox2").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) { // 9 is tab key
         event.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent().nextAll('.fm-req:has(.defaultTextBox2)').first().find('.defaultTextBox2').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to find the next .fm-req that has a .defaultTextBox2 (some might not).

Comment: Updated my code but as Fabio suggested you should use tabindex.